# How you get the square containing a multipolyline

Tags: postgis, area

I use ST_Union to group a few lines. But realize some lines aren't supposed to be joined together after all. I would like to calculate the extent of the multipolyline so if the area is too big probably shouldn't have been joined together.

I need something like ST_Area but for multipolyline instead of polygons.

If I get the square I can use ST_Area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think st_extent() is doing what you want.

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Extent.html